# "Mocking out" calls to private methods in a method being tested when using Fakes

Tags: c#, unit-testing, microsoft-fakes

I am using Microsoft Fakes to analyze a very long method, to re-factor it and to gain a better understanding of it.  I have isolated a couple of lines that look like a good candidate to be re-factored into a separate private method.  The approach I am taking is not to modify the code by hand (only use out-of-the-box re-factoring) in order to minimize the fallout from my changes.  Here is the question:
Once I re-factor the lines in question into a separate private method, I would like to eliminate all the setup code associated with those lines (and the new private method that wraps them) and just "mock out" that call by providing a default canned answer.  This smells like a stub/shim but we are talking about the class under test so I need the class to execute it's code except for "mocked out" methods.  In Rhino Mocks I would use a PartialMock to stub out such calls (after making them virtual first!!!) but can Fakes help me in this situation? Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to overwrite private methods (mock private methods) you do this with shims

Some good reads:
http://adamprescott.net/2012/08/28/unit-testing-and-private-methods/
and 
http://adamprescott.net/2012/08/21/a-shim-ple-tutorial-with-microsoft-fakes/

The example has a public method `Read` which internally calls `SecretMethod` which is private...

```
var target = new FileReader("foo");
var shim = new ShimFileReader(target);
bool calledShimMethod = false;
shim.SecretMethod = () => 
{
   calledShimMethod = true;
   return "bar";
};

target.Read();
```

Answer (score 1):

As another answer mentioned, shims are the way to do this. However, be aware that by using a shim, your test is now tied to the implementation of the public method. In many cases, there isn't anything you can do about that, particularly if you're testing code you didn't write. Just remember that testing the implementation means your test will be more prone to breaking when code is changed.

Having said that, you do manage to escape the implementation details causing a large amount of setup, which is a plus, so you could be heading toward something *less* brittle.

I use shims quite a bit on a project I'm working on, but like me you should probably feel bad every time you need to, since it's a fairly good indicator of bad design. The best way to avoid it is the Strategy pattern (and DI in general) since then you can rely on stubs.